# How to get real sql exception through enterprise-library?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, enterprise-library

When current user does not have permission to execute procedure enterprise-library return message like "The stored procedure 'procedure_name' doesn't exist." Instead real sql message :
"The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'procedure_name', database 'DatabaseName', schema 'dbo'."

Please tell me how can i get real sql exception through enterprise-library?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Enterprise Library Contrib : [SqlException Wrap Handler](http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SqlExceptionWrapHandler41)

Comment: I tried this 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "Data Access Policy"))
        throw;
}

But I get new exception : "The requested exception policy 'Data Access Policy' could not be found."

Comment: did you add the required references?

Comment: yes, 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.dll already was added.
Is it possible cause of exception my old version of EnterpriseLibrary 2.0?